# Why cloudwatch alarm status is always ok?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

Im trying to create a cloudwatch alarm for when NumberOfMessagesPublished from a specific topic are > 4 I want to send a notification to subscribers from a specific topic.

I already have the cloudwatch alarm configure in aws managment console.

And now I have this code below to send a notification, and Im sending a lot of notifications but the cloudwatch alarm status is always OK.

Do you have any idea why this isnt working?

```
def sendNotification(email):
    c = boto.sns.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
    message = "Hi."
    message_subject = "Dados enviados para processamento"
    topicArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:test" 
    publication = c.publish(topicArn, message, subject=message_subject) 


sendSNSNotification(test@mail.test")
```

Comment: If you login to the AWS console and manually publish to the topic.  Does it work?

Comment: Then your cloudwatch alarm is not setup correctly.  Please post what your cloudwatch alarm config is.  Your settings are not triggering the alarm.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/MonitorSNSwithCloudWatch.html

Comment: This guide gives a better explanation of how the Cloudwatch alarms handle the triggers over time periods.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html

Comment: First of all there is an error in your code ( not related with Cloudwatch ) sendSNSNotification(test@mail.test") " is missing . Second how did you configure your alarm? Did you choose "Sum" as statistics?